# How to redirect HTTP requests on a Python App on Bluemix to HTTPS only?

Tags: python, http, https, ibm-cloud

I have python app on Bluemix and would like to make it accessible over https only. By default I can connect both via http and https. Want to restrict access via https only. So what is the best way to disable http access, or redirect request to https only?

Comment: This might help you: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16016/how-do-i-enforce-ssl-for-my-bluemix-application.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ralphearle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3692258/ralphearle) mentioned in his answer, Bluemix proxy server terminates the SSL, so you can look into the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to find out if request comes from `http` or `https`.

See below a simple example based on the Python starter code from Bluemix. I added the `RedirectHandler` class to check for the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header value and redirects the request to `https` if it not `https`.

```
import os
try:
  from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
  from SocketServer import TCPServer as Server
except ImportError:
  from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
  from http.server import HTTPServer as Server

class RedirectHandler(Handler):
  def do_HEAD(self):
    if ('X-Forwarded-Proto' in self.headers and 
            self.headers['X-Forwarded-Proto'] != 'https'):
        self.send_response(301)
        self.send_header("Location", 'https://' + self.headers['Host'] + self.path)
        self.end_headers() 
  def do_GET(self):
     self.do_HEAD()
     Handler.do_GET(self)

# Read port selected by the cloud for our application
PORT = int(os.getenv('PORT', 8000))
# Change current directory to avoid exposure of control files
os.chdir('static')

httpd = Server(("", PORT), RedirectHandler)
try:
  print("Start serving at port %i" % PORT)
  httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
httpd.server_close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bluemix proxy server terminates the SSL, so that all traffic looks like HTTP to your app. However, the proxy also adds a special HTTP header named $WSSC with a value that can be either http or https. Check this header and, if the value is set to http, then change it to https.

As Adam pointed out in his comment, the IBM forum has further discussion of this approach: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/16016/how-do-i-enforce-ssl-for-my-bluemix-application.html

Comment: It is better to check for the X-Forwarded-Proto header instead.